# How to change the color of a column in jTable?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have kept some colors for animals in Database.
Say there are four animals and have assigned four colors for each in Database.
In jTable when i select an animal of my choice ,i need to the color also to be applied.

Ex-If i click Elephant ,the assigned color should be my background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell formatting is the responsibility of the `TableCellRenderer`

Take a look at [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more details

Comment: @MohammedImranN Nice to see you making an attempt on your own, well done ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer- I have tried  TableCellRenderer to display the color by using hardcoding the color.

But i wanna do Dynamically.in DB,i have kept the color in RGB format,how can i decode it and make it to sit in the exact animal's location?

The reason why i kept color code in DB is user can choose the color's of animal of their own..

Can you give some more idea on this ?

Comment: 1- Make sure you have loaded the color values.  Don't know if they are directly related to the animal row or not, but you should produce a model that allows you to get easy access to this method. 2- Is the color packed int value or seperate RGB values (R, G, B as byte/int)

Comment: You can create a simple `Color` object using [`Color(int, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20int,%20int%29) (R, G, B)